# How to loop through two arrays with same key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm posting the below arrays, where each checkbox/checkbox tag are linked with a key (i.e. each category check box is linked with a "worldwide" checkbox):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[1]" value=10 > Politics
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide[1]" value=1 > Worldwide

<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[2]" value=20 > Sports
<input type="checkbox" name="worldwide[2]" value=1 > Worldwide
```

I received them in the controller and trying to store the values.

```
 $catprefs = $request['catpref'];
 $worldwide = $request['worldwide'];

foreach($catprefs as $key => $value and $worldwide as $key => $value2){

      $save_catp = new Cpref();
      $save_catp->user_id = $user_id;
      $save_catp->qatype = $value;
      $save_catp->wwide= $value2;
      $save_catp->type = 1;
      $save_catp->save();
```

What would be the syntax for the above foreach loop ?

P.S : Please note that the arrays linked together via key could be different in size because a category could be selected while "worldwide" could be left unselected (i.e. array_combine() requires equal size arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the worldwide key is set then add it's value other wise set to default value.

```
foreach($catprefs as $key => $value){

  $save_catp = new Cpref();
  $save_catp->user_id = $user_id;
  $save_catp->qatype = $value;
  $save_catp->wwide= (array_key_exists($key, $worldwide) ? $worldwide[$key] : 'default value');
  $save_catp->type = 1;
  $save_catp->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$catprefs = $request['catpref'];
$worldwide = $request['worldwide'];

foreach($catprefs as $key => $value){
   $save_catp = new Cpref();
   $save_catp->user_id = $user_id;
   $save_catp->qatype = $value;
   $save_catp->wwide= isset($worldwide[$key]) ? $worldwide[$key] : 1;
   $save_catp->type = 1;
   $save_catp->save();
}
```

Comment: I received error :Undefined offset: 3 at this line : $save_catp->wwide= $worldwide[$key];

Comment: I tried and it didn't give an error, but now all categories are having the wwide set to 1 even the ones that have the worldwide checkbox not selected.

Comment: $save_catp->wwide= isset($worldwide[$key]) ? $worldwide[$key] : 1;

Change '1' with your default value and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions could be "chunking" those inputs. You can use multidimensional arrays for form inputs.

Try to rename them like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="set[1][catpref]" value=10> Politics
<input type="checkbox" name="set[1][worldwide]" value=1> Worldwide

<input type="checkbox" name="set[2][catpref]" value=20> Sports
<input type="checkbox" name="set[2][worldwide]" value=1> Worldwide
```

Then your foreach loop will look something like this:

```
foreach ($request['set'] as ['catpref' => $catpref, 'worldwide' => $worldwide]) {
    var_dump($catpref, $worldwide);
}
```

Comment: I received error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Don't blindly copy-paste this code. Did you change checkboxes name attributes? What's inside `$request` variable? Please show me `var_dump($request)` just before loop.